# Исключение из выборки элементов нескольких групп

Tags: css

То что можно выбрать элементы по какому-то атрибуту ни для кого ни секрет.
Что-то вроде `input[type='text']` выберет все поля ввода с соответствующим атрибутом, как и обратный вариант `input[type!='text']` выберет все поля не относящиеся к этому типу.

Если же нужно выбрать несколько вариантов, то можно их перечислить через запятую `input[type='text'], input[type='email']`.

Но как выбрать все элементы не относящиеся к нескольким группам? Допустим выбрать все кроме `type='button'` и `type='submit'`.

Пока что решил в лоб. Но мне кажется должен быть более аккуратный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]) {
  border: 2px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="tel">
<input type="password">
<input type="email">
<input type="button">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Воистину всё гениальное просто.
Спасибо.